# ¿Puedo pasar un dato en segundos directamente a una fecha?

Tags: python, date, datetime

Con este fragmento de codigo de python pretendo restar a d1_fecha 3600 segundos.
Lo consigo en `d2_fecha_sec`. Pero una vez tengo `d2_fecha_sec` no sé como pasarlo de nuevo a una fecha en formato `datetime.datetime`.

```
d1_fecha = datetime.datetime(2020,7,1,12,5,30) 
d1_fecha_sec = time.mktime(fecha.timetuple())

d2_fecha_sec = d1_fecha_sec - 3600
#d2_fecha ?? en datetime.datetime
```

Comment: 3600 segundos es una hora, la puedes restar directamente en la creación de la fecha: `print( datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( time.mktime( (2020,7,1,12-1,5,30,0,0,0) ) ) )`, incluso puedes hacer `30-3600`.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una fecha a partir de un *timestamp* (que es como se denomina el tener un contador de segundos). En tu caso sería así:

```py
import datetime, time
d1_fecha = datetime.datetime(2020,7,1,12,5,30) 
d1_fecha_sec = time.mktime(d1_fecha.timetuple())

d2_fecha_sec = d1_fecha_sec - 3600
d2_fecha = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d2_fecha_sec)
print(d2_fecha)
```

Y obtendrás el resultado `2020-07-01 11:05:30` que es lo que buscabas.

Sin embargo no necesitas complicar tanto las cosas si lo que quieres es restarle una hora a una fecha dada. Puedes hacerlo así:

```
d1_fecha = datetime.datetime(2020,7,1,12,5,30) 
d2_fecha = d1_fecha - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

que produce el mismo resultado.